# Faster ways to access subsets through LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is a question about SPEED - there are a LOT of records to be accessed.

**Basic Information About The Problem**

As an example, we will have three tables in a Database.

Relations: 
Order-ProductInOrder is One-To-Many (an order can have many products in the order)
ProductInOrder- Product is One-To-One (a product in the order is represented by one product)

```
public class Order {
  public bool Processed { get; set; }
  // this determines whether the order has been processed
  // - orders that have do not go through this again
  public int OrderID { get; set; } //PK
  public decimal TotalCost{ get; set; }
  public List<ProductInOrder> ProductsInOrder;
  // from one-to-many relationship with ProductInOrder
  // the rest is irrelevant and will not be included here
}
//represents an product in an order - an order can have many products
public class ProductInOrder {
  public int PIOD { get; set; } //PK
  public int Quantity{ get; set; }
  public int OrderID { get; set; }//FK
  public Order TheOrder { get; set; }
  // from one-to-many relationship with Order
  public int ProductID { get; set; } //FK
  public Product TheProduct{ get; set; }
  //from one-to-one relationship with Product
}
//information about a product goes here
public class Product {
  public int ProductID { get; set; } //PK
  public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } //the cost per item
  // the rest is irrelevant to this question
}
```

Suppose we receive a batch of orders where we need to apply discounts to and find the total price of the order. This could apply to anywhere from 10,000 to over 100,000 orders. The way this works is that if an order has 5 or more products where the cost each is $100, we will give a 10% discount on the total price.

**What I Have Tried**

I have tried the following:

```
//this part gets the product in order with over 5 items
List<Order> discountedOrders = orderRepo
  .Where(p => p.Processed == false)
  .ToList();
List<ProductInOrder> discountedProducts = discountedOrders
  .SelectMany(p => p.ProductsInOrder)
  .Where(q => q.Quantity >=5 )
  .ToList();
discountedProducts = discountedProducts
  .Where(p => p.Product.UnitPrice >= 100.00)
  .ToList();
discountOrders = discountedOrders
  .Where(p => discountProducts.Any(q => q.OrderID == p.OrderID))
  .ToList();
```

This is very slow and takes forever to run, and when I run integration tests on it, the test seems to time out. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to **not** call `ToList` after every query.

When you call `ToList` on a query it is executed and the objects are loaded from the database in memory. Any subsequent query based on the results from the first query is performed in memory on the list instead of performing it directly in the database. What you want to do here is to execute the whole query on the database and return only those results which verify all your conditions.

```
var discountedOrders = orderRepo
  .Where(p=>p.Processed == false);
var discountedProducts = discountedOrders
  .SelectMany(p=>p.ProductsInOrder)
  .Where(q=>q.Quantity >=5);
discountedProducts = discountedProducts
  .Where(p=>p.Product.UnitPrice >= 100.00);
discountOrders = discountedOrders
  .Where(p=>discountProducts.Any(q=>q.OrderID == p.OrderID));
```

Comment: This is especially true if there is a IQueryable behind.

Comment: is there a way to do counting faster? also, when i take a sneak preview at the contents of the var, it times out.

Comment: @tehdoommarine I don't understand what you mean. Just call `Count()` to get the number of elements returned by your query.

Comment: ah nevermind. works perfectly. was doing the count on a list, which is slow and grueling

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, combining those calls will speed it up some. Try this:

```
discountOrders =  orderRepo.Where(p=>p.Processed == false && p.SelectMany(q=>q.ProductsInOrder).Where(r=>r.Quantity >=5 && r.Product.UnitPrice >= 100.00 && r.OrderID == p.OrderId).Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Note that this isn't tested. I hope I got the logic right-- I think I did, but let me know if I didn't.

Comment: Bosh. Now this can run in the DB rather than bringing all those rows to the client. Any inefficiency now can probably be traced to missing indexes.

Comment: You **don't** need to put everything in **one** statement. Just don't call `ToList` after every statement and everything will be run as one statement on the database.

Comment: See Myth 8 from [10 LINQ Myths](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/10linqmyths.aspx)

Comment: @david.s Good article. I was aware of that, but (and correct me if I'm wrong here) I believe the change of order of operations I introduced while putting them into one statement should speed things up inherently. You're right though -- I made it out to seem like it was the actual combining that was making the impact.

Comment: @spender I'm a little confused by the use of `bosh` here, lol

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @PhillipSchmidt, you could rationalize your Linq

```
var discountEligibleOrders =
 allOrders
   .Where(order => !order.Processed 
                   && order
                    .ProductsInOrder
                    .Any(pio => pio.TheProduct.UnitPrice >= 100M 
                                && pio.Quantity >= 5))
```

Removing all those nasty `ToList` statements is a great start because you're pulling potentially significantly larger sets from the db to your app than you need to. Let the database do the work.

To get each order and its price (assuming a discounted price of 0.9*listed price):

```
var ordersAndPrices =
 allOrders
   .Where(order => !order.Processed)
   .Select(order => new {
                     order, 
                     isDiscounted = order
                       .ProductsInOrder
                       .Any(pio => pio.TheProduct.UnitPrice >= 100M 
                                   && pio.Quantity >= 5)
                    })
   .Select(x => new {
                  order = x.order, 
                  price = x.order
                           .ProductsInOrder
                           .Sum(p=> p.Quantity 
                                    * p.TheProduct.UnitPrice
                                    * (x.isDiscounted ? 0.9M : 1M))});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have an accepted answer but please try this for added speed - PLINQ (Parallel LINQ) this will take a list of 4000 and if you have 4 cores it will filter 1000 on each core and then collate the results.

```
  List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
  var parallelQuery = (from o in orders.AsParallel()
                       where !o.Processed
                       select o.ProductsInOrder.Where(x => x.Quantity >= 5 &&
                                                           x.TheProduct.UnitPrice >= 100.00 && 
                                                           orders.Any(x => x.OrderID = x.OrderID));
```

Please see here:

In many scenarios, PLINQ can significantly increase the speed of LINQ to Objects queries by using all available cores on the host computer more efficiently. This increased performance brings high performance computing power onto the desktop

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx

Comment: Hmm. if there are a large number of processed orders and orders is an IQueryable from the database, then this will be horribly inefficient, pulling a whole bunch of already processed items from the DB. Keeping everything in the database will allow the DB to make its own mind up as to whether or not the workload needs parallelization. Also worth bearing in mind that unless explicitly loaded, accessing naviagtional properties such as `ProductsInOrder` will cause another DB hit. ... for every order.

Comment: I just thought this was overall from LINQ with objects didn't realise it was using a SQL database or entity framework for a minute. I suppose it's always good to know that you can speed plain LINQ up with objects, even if this was from a repository for entity framework?

Comment: Absolutely. OP doesn't make datasource clear, but I assume this is coming from a DB as I see the statement "we will have three tables"

Answer (score -1):

move that into 1 query, but actually you should move this into a SSIS package or a sql job. You could easily make this a stored proc that runs in less than a second.